# How to set the TabPanel Tab Width and Tab Height?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to set the TabPanel Tab Width and Tab Height?

I tried:

```
var myTabPanel  = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {  
   fullscreen: true,
   tabBarPosition: 'top', 
   resizeTabs: true,
   tabWidth: 300, 
   //minTabWidth: 300
        ....
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Where did you find these configs : resizeTabs, tabWidth, minTabWidth ?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?88910-Ext.TabPanel-increase-tab-size

Comment: This is a discussion on EXTJS 3 not Sencha Touch 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all that happening inside sencha `css` files. You need to modify it there.

Answer (score 0):

good news,

I've found the way to do this programatically.

```
//assuming you are using the MVC structure as suggested
/*In the controller class of your view with the tab panel you must have reference to the tab panel in refs config.
The reference name for this case will be: myTabpanel
*/

//somewhere in the controller class
var tabPanelItems = this.getMyTabpanel().getItems; //get all the items inside the tab panel (if i'm not mistaken this will also return some "extra" item which is not panel
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  //due to that extra item i mentioned, need to make sure current item is a tab by confirming "tab" property existence
  if (panels.items[i].tab) {
    panels.items[i].setWidth('100px');
    panels.items[i].setHeight('25px');
  }
}
```

And that is it.
Key point is that its a Tab-panel (tab with panel) therefore to configure just the tab part we first need to get the tab part otherwise we'll just configuring the panel part by default.